# How to move my title position with background image in Xaringan?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

Hi I added background image for my title page but once I added the following in order to move my title to top and left, the background image was gone.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

`titleSlideClass: [top, left]`

```
---
title: "ECON"
subtitle: "Course Outline"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "University"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      titleSlideClass: [top, left]
 
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create your own title slide. To do that, as per the [documentation](https://slides.yihui.org/xaringan/#27)

> If you'd like to create your own title slide, disable xaringan's title slide with the seal = FALSE option of moon_reader.

So seal xaringan's default title slide and create your own slide using `rmarkdown::metadata` and control the title position using `class: title-slide, top, left`

```
---
title: "ECON"
subtitle: "Course Outline"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "University"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    seal: false
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      
 
---
class: title-slide, top, left, inverse
background-image: url(lights.jpg)
background-size: cover

# **`r rmarkdown::metadata$title`**
## **`r rmarkdown::metadata$subtitle`**
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$author`
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$institute`
### `r Sys.Date()`

---
```

Comment: Where do I have to write the second part of your answer? In css file, correct?

Comment: No, you would write exactly like written here. There's no css code here. `class`,  `background-size` these are part of xaringan, AFAIK

Comment: Hi sorry again. I was not so attentive last time. Only part that still does not work is date. It still shows up like `r Sys.Date()`, not actual date.

Comment: @joe, see the update.